# Production build failed in netlify - Vue3

Tags: vuejs3, netlify

The npm run build is failing due to some typescript error of type checks and my build stack is Vue3 + Vuetify.

How to make it work?

```
12:41:48 AM: $ npm run build
12:41:48 AM: > skinulate@8.1.3 build
12:41:48 AM: > vue-cli-service build
12:41:48 AM: All browser targets in the browserslist configuration have supported ES module.
12:41:48 AM: Therefore we don't build two separate bundles for differential loading.
12:41:48 AM: -  Building for production...
12:42:57 AM:  ERROR  Failed to compile with 6 errors7:12:57 PM
12:42:57 AM:  error  in node_modules/vee-validate/node_modules/type-fest/source/camel-case.d.ts:25:32
12:42:57 AM: TS1005: '?' expected.
12:42:57 AM:     23 |   OutputString extends string = '',
12:42:57 AM:     24 | > = Words extends [
12:42:57 AM:   > 25 |   infer FirstWord extends string,
12:42:57 AM:        |                                 ^
12:42:57 AM:     26 |   ...infer RemainingWords extends string[],
12:42:57 AM:     27 | ]
12:42:57 AM:     28 |   ? Options['preserveConsecutiveUppercase'] extends true
12:42:57 AM:  error  in node_modules/vee-validate/node_modules/type-fest/source/camel-case.d.ts:26:42
12:42:57 AM: TS1005: '?' expected.
12:42:57 AM:     24 | > = Words extends [
12:42:57 AM:     25 |   infer FirstWord extends string,
12:42:57 AM:   > 26 |   ...infer RemainingWords extends string[],
12:42:57 AM:        |                                           ^
12:42:57 AM:     27 | ]
12:42:57 AM:     28 |   ? Options['preserveConsecutiveUppercase'] extends true
12:42:57 AM:     29 |       ? `${Capitalize<FirstWord>}${CamelCaseFromArray<RemainingWords, Options>}`
12:42:57 AM:  error  in node_modules/vee-validate/node_modules/type-fest/source/join.d.ts:59:36
12:42:57 AM: TS1005: '?' expected.
```

Comment: I suggest to move your project to Vite as the recommend build tool for vue projects nowadays

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Thank you! Sure, I'll definitely try this.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Thank you so much for suggesting to use Vite, It got worked perfectly fine.

Comment: you are welcome! also I've added the comment as an answer so you could accept it (the checkbox) and upvote (the arrow up). that way i'll be rewarded and motivated to help you in the future, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to move your project to Vite as the recommend build tool for vue projects nowadays